# Вывод меню на всех страницах конкретного раздела

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть у меня на сайте несколько разделов (о здоровье, еда). Мне надо сделать в разделе еда меню, в котором отображаются пункты завтрак, обед, ужин. Но возникает следующая проблема, при переходе на страницу выбранного пункта, меню(с пунктами завтрак, обед, ужин) вообще не отображаются, как сей момент исправить?